# Devise: Don't redirect after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In `Devise`, after updating user, it automatically redirects but I want to only return JSON since I am building SPA. I tried with following

```
def after_update_path_for(resource)
    { updated: true }
end
```

but it still redirects with this parameter via

```
Turbolinks.visit("http://localhost:3000/users?update=true", {"action":"replace"})
```

Rendering JSON gives double render error.

Can I disable redirect and only render JSON?

Comment: Devise doesn't support this out of the box. So you need to overload Devise controllers and tell them to render JSON.

Comment: @JagjotSingh i know, in fact, after_update_path_for overloads Devise controller method for path to redirect after update, but i can't find where to overload redirection itself

Comment: I'll explain the double render error that you were facing. The `after_update_path` overrides only and only the path after update. So you cannot render anything in that method as it will be used for redirection. If you want to return anything other than HTML, you'd need to overload `RegistrationsController` and add `respond_to :json` for it to respond to JSON requests. Redirection is overloaded in controller which you'll overload :)